# How to use input on dashboard page in other page R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a dashboard with multiple pages. Now I have an input field on one dashboard where I want to use this input value on a different dashboard page (in different module). Does anyone know how to do this? Below you can find the Picker Input from which I want to use the value on a different dashboard page.

```
output$UI_selectionHierarchy <- renderUI({

grouplist_1 <- list("Search.group.1","Item.number") 
 tagList(
  #p(h3("Define")),
  p(tags$i("Define the ...")),
  pickerInput(inputId = "selectHierarchy1",
              label = "Select first (most general) hierarchy:",
              choices = list(
                "Hierarchies" = grouplist_1),
                #"Sporadic demand products" = productlist_2),
              selected = NULL,
              options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `none-selected-text` = "Select hierarchy", `live-search` = TRUE, title = "Select hierarchy"),
              multiple = FALSE
  ),
```

When I try do use the value `input$selectHierarchy1` on a different dashboard (different module) nothing happens.

Comment: is it possible to put it on the sidebar?

Comment: @Roman could you maybe elaborate a bit more on that?